# ffmpeg output file is too large

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to burn a subtitle file(.srt) to a mp4 video.My command is:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -vf subtitles=input.srt out.mp4`

It output a video with a good quality,but its size is 1.12GB while the input file is 213MB.

I think the problem is kbps of output file is too high.the bitrate of input file is 568 kb/s but the output file is 3154 kb/s.

So I want to set the kps,now here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v 569k -minrate 568k -maxrate 570k -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -vf subtitles=input.srt out.mp4
```

Although the output file become smaller(538MB),the video's quality is awful(Compare with input file)...
So how to make the output file smaller and in good quality?Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -vf subtitles=input.srt out.mp4
```

This uses the x264 library instead of mpeg4. It's newer and has better compression. You might try playing around with the 23 being passed to the `-crf` option. The [Constant Rate Factor](http://slhck.info/articles/crf) will give better results and higher file sizes at lower values, and poorer results with smaller files sizes at higher values. Try for something between 20 and 30.

If you're sure you want to stick with mpeg4, [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4) details the options a bit more and might help.

And if you want to make your subtitles look nicer, take a look at the different [options for subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1), such as using different fonts.

Comment: Thanks,it works well.So my problem is how to choose a encoder?It depends more on input file or output file?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. ffmpeg can read many, many different video types, and write to many different types. I don't know much about mpeg4, except that it's older than x264. As long as your input file is of good quality, you should be able to get your output to be of good quality, and of similar file size, although there are a lot of different quality options, so it can be very confusing.

Comment: Something else you might want to read up on is doing Two-Pass Encoding. This link gives some details for x264: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass

Comment: It can certainly take a while to get your brain wrapped around all the different options and processes going on. Though if you can manage to stick with it and learn a few of the options, ffmpeg is a powerful tool.

Comment: May be I should try out encoding different files and I will use it properly.xD

Comment: Now I install ffmpeg correctly on my Ubuntu.Although the output file size is smaller than before (still bigger than input file), the quality (especially its color has a little different from input file's) is not good enough,has any way to solve that?

Comment: I'd suggest trying a smaller value for `crf`. If 23 isn't giving the quality you need, try 21 or 20. I'm afraid I can't help much with the colour. You may want to read up on colorspaces.

Comment: That's OK,may be i need do more research.anyway,thanks for your time.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger Isn't 0 and 20+ a big gap? If 0 means best quality, doesn't that mean I will lose a lot of quality?

Comment: @user2675516 It *is* a big gap, but check out this page for more details: http://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html
A CRF of 0 means lossless. This will be great quality, but huge file sizes. You've got to make the tradeoff somewhere, and a value in the neighbourhood of 20 will give pretty decent quality and pretty good file sizes. After reading through the link, I'd suggest experimenting with a short clip you want to convert. Try a variety of CRF values. Compare the file sizes as well as your own subjective opinion on the video quality.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger I find lossless conversion weird. Why when I pick CRF of 0, my file size becomes bigger than the original file but it is impossible for the converted file to have a higher quality than the original file right? In that sense, what is causing the growth in file size?

Comment: @user2675516 Yes, it's impossible for the new file to have higher quality than the original. As for the file size growth, I'm afraid I'm out of my depth. Perhaps the data is getting stored less efficiently? I'm not sure.